# Ionic Local Notification without playing sound

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

```
this.localNotification.schedule({
            id: req.notificationID,
            title: req.name,
            text: req.status,
            progressBar: { value: req.progressValue },
            wakeup: false,
            launch: false,
            sticky: true,
            sound: null
          });
```

How to show local notification without playing a sound?. I tested with *sound=null*, *sound=''* but no change. It always plays sound while sheduling and updating notification. Is there any way to disable the sound?

Comment: you can try with `` empty inside example  sound: ``

Comment: sound: `` not working

Comment: delete sound : null example = this.localNotification.schedule({
            id: req.notificationID,
            title: req.name,
            text: req.status,
            progressBar: { value: req.progressValue },
            wakeup: false,
            launch: false,
            sticky: true
          });

Comment: playing its default sound

Comment: try sound: false

Comment: tried but no change